# Disable structure view of PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I am looking for how to deactivate the structure view of PhpStorm and remove the dropdown.

What I want to disable:

[image: what i want to disable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **disable "Show Members" option**.

1. Either right click on the "Project" tool window header or click on the Cog icon
2. Ensure that "Tree Appearance | Show members" is unchecked.

[image]